# Display each element of a queryset separated with an <br> inside of a <td> in django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

**Model**

```
class Tesis(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
    año = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    carrera = models.ForeignKey(
        Carrera, related_name="tesis_carrera", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(
        Tutor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="tutor_tesis")
    alumno = models.ManyToManyField(Alumno, related_name="alumno_tesis")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tesis"
        verbose_name = "Tesis"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descripcion
```

**VIEW**

```
class Listar_TesisListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

   queryset = Tesis.objects.all()
   template_name =  "listar_tesis_cargadas.html"
   model = Tesis
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="table-container">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="has-text-centered" colspan="6">
                  LISTADO DE TESIS
                </th>
              </tr>
              <th>DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
              <th>AÑO</th>
              <th>CARRERA</th>
              <th>TUTOR</th>
              <th>ALUMNO</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for item in object_list %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ item.descripcion }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.año}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.carrera }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.tutor}}</td>
                <td><{{item.alumno.all}}</td>
                
                
                {% for al in item.alumno.all %}
                                       
                <td>  {{al}} <br> </td>
                {% endfor %} 
               </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

**WHAT I GET**

[image]

**WHAT I WANT**

In the same `<td>` when the alumno queryset has 2 elements print the first and then make a breaking line and print the next one. Like this:

**Alumno Depru1**

**Alu2 depru2**


I also tried this:

```
{% if item.alumno.count > 1  %}
{% for al in item.alumno.all %}
                                       
<td>  {{al}} <br>{{al}} </td>
{% endfor %} 
{% else %}
{% for al in item.alumno.all %}
                                             
<td> {{al}} </td>
{% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

and I get:
[image]

**Also tried:**

```
% for al in item.alumno.all %}
<td>  {{al.0}} <br>{{al.1}} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can I access the elements of the queryset separately and print them in the format {{al.0}} or {{al[0]}}
2. Is there a better way of doing this kind of logic in the views and just pass it to the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want all the alumno items in a single `<td>` cell? Render `<td>` before the `for` loop and `</td>` after?

```
<td> 
{% for al in item.alumno.all %}              
    {{ al }} <br> 
{% endfor %} 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HOW IT WAS SOLVED:**

```
{% if item.alumno.count > 1  %}
<td>
{% for al in item.alumno.all %}
{{al}} 
<br>
{% endfor %} 
</td>
{% else %}
{% for al in item.alumno.all %}
<td>{{al}}</td> 
{% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```